# Dropdown items are not formatted properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

```
Rails 6
Bootstrap 4
```

I am trying to create a navigation bar, using dropdown menus, with buttons. I am expecting the highlighted dropdown item, to be blue, but it's not. Please see picture.

[image]

Here's my code:

```
#NaviagationBar.btn-group
  .dropdown
    button#BooksMenu.btn.btn-primary.dropdown-toggle aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" data-toggle="dropdown" type="button"
      | Books
    .dropdown-menu aria-labelledby="BooksMenu"
      button.btn.dropdown-item type="button"  Action
      button.btn.dropdown-item type="button"  Another action
      button.btn.dropdown-item type="button"  Something else here
  .dropdown
    button#CardsMenu.btn.btn-primary.dropdown-toggle aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" data-toggle="dropdown" type="button"
      | Cards
    .dropdown-menu aria-labelledby="CardsMenu"
      button.btn.dropdown-item type="button"  Action
      button.btn.dropdown-item type="button"  Another action
      button.btn.dropdown-item type="button"  Something else here
```

Any ideas?

EDIT:

The menu items, turn into a blue button when I click on it, but not when I hover over it.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `dropdown-item btn` class by `btn btn-primary w-100` from your dropdown-item button ?

Replace :

```
<button class="dropdown-item btn" href="#">Action</button>
```

By :

```
<button class="btn btn-primary w-100" href="#">Action</button>
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Dropdown button
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
        <button class="btn btn-primary w-100" href="#">Action</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary w-100" href="#">Another action</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary w-100" href="#">Something else here</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: btn-primary, does not have the same properties as dropdown-item, and will not respond to keyboard menu interactions the same way

Answer (score 0):

You can write a customer scss rule to target the dropdown and the items within to change color on hover or focus. [CssTricks - Hover-within](https://css-tricks.com/solved-with-css-dropdown-menus/#article-header-id-1) this link talks about hover-within pseudo selector. But it also explains that you could also do it with just focus and or hover